# Conditional union in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I have a query which gives me 2 columns,

```
select

    name as name,
    code as code
    
from
    table1
    
UNION
    
select

    name as name,
    code as code
    
from
    table2
```

I would like to apply one more union in the result if from the above query i did not get a row with `name as 'Default'`. So if above query didnt have a record with default name i need to have 1 more union with above query:

```
select
        'Default' as name,
        code as code
from
    table1
where condition = condition
```

I tried putting first query in a view and use not exists function in second query but it gives column not found error.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I understood the question: lines #1 - 9 represent sample data; one of rows contains the `Default` name, so your resulting query should return the `union`-ed result *as is*:

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (name, code) as
  3    (select 'Little', 1 from dual union all
  4     select 'Foot'  , 2 from dual
  5    ),
  6  table2 (name, code) as
  7    (select 'Default', 3 from dual union all   --> Default is here
  8     select 'Oracle' , 4 from dual
  9    ),
 10  -- the "original" union
 11  oriun as
 12    (select name, code from table1
 13     union
 14     select name, code from table2
 15    )
 16  select name, code from oriun
 17  union
 18  select 'Default' name, null code from table1
 19  where not exists (select null from oriun
 20                    where name = 'Default'
 21                   )
 22  order by code;

NAME          CODE
------- ----------
Little           1
Foot             2
Default          3
Oracle           4

SQL>
```

But, if there's no `Default` in those tables (see change made in line #7), then you'd get an "extra" `Default` row:

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (name, code) as
  3    (select 'Little', 1 from dual union all
  4     select 'Foot'  , 2 from dual
  5    ),
  6  table2 (name, code) as
  7    (select 'xxx', 3 from dual union all     --> No more Default here
  8     select 'Oracle' , 4 from dual
  9    ),
 10  -- the "original" union
 11  oriun as
 12    (select name, code from table1
 13     union
 14     select name, code from table2
 15    )
 16  select name, code from oriun
 17  union
 18  select 'Default' name, null code from table1
 19  where not exists (select null from oriun
 20                    where name = 'Default'
 21                   )
 22  order by code;

NAME          CODE
------- ----------
Little           1
Foot             2
xxx              3
Oracle           4
Default

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have order by in union you need to put it inside a view or create a block with select * from (.. order by)

Comment: Were you answering someone else's question? Because, how is this related to the problem? What does `order by` have to do with it?